# ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_URI_v4 Not available

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile, containers, amazon-ecs

I have an ECS cluster which has a few services.
All the containers are running on EC2 mode.

**Objective**: I want to get the service name inside the container.

**Steps taken**

1. Enabled "enable_ecs_managed_tags: true"
2. RAN `wget -qO- $ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_URI/taskWithTags`
   -->this does not give me the `aws:ecs:serviceName` which I need.
3. So I ran `wget -qO- $ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_URI_V4/taskWithTags`
   -->this doesn't return anything at all.

What am I doing wrong? Or is there another way to get the service name to which the container belong to.

BTW I've double checked if the tags are there. They are there as required in the tasks which can be seen from the AWS console.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get service Name of Task under aws fargate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59395468/get-service-name-of-task-under-aws-fargate)

Answer (score 0):

Try with `${ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_URI_V4}/taskWithTags`

[Task metadata endpoint version 4](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-metadata-endpoint-v4.html)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem that the [task metadata endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-metadata-endpoint-v4.html#task-metadata-endpoint-v4-response) returns the `service name` the task belongs to.